# how to post few images with message on facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm interested to create a post on my page or my feed with few images from my album and some text which will contain some message and some link / handle ( to facebook friend or page )

For now i've tried to create an album, add few images to it but i don't have almost no control of what th description is going to be.

```
    FB.login(function () {
        FB.api("/me/accounts", function (response) {
            FB.api(
                "/usetoken/albums",
                 "POST",
                {
                    "name": "My Album",
                    "message": "Some Message",
                    "access_token": response.data[0].access_token
                },
                function (response) {
                    debugger;
                    if (response && !response.error) {
                        debugger;
                        /* handle the result */
                    }
                }
            );
        });
    }, { scope: 'publish_actions,user_photos,manage_pages' });


function post_image() {
    FB.api(
        "/albumid/photos",
        "POST",
        {
            "url": "imageurl",
            "access_token": access_token
        },
        function (response) {

            if (response && !response.error) {
                debugger;
                /* handle the result */
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Is a NodeJS project?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to publish rich content, you should use [Notes](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/note#publishing).

When you create an album, it will be shown as a status of your page/profile. The status message of that status will be the album description. So you can insert your message into the album description, and you should be ok.